# Stack Exchange Language Policy

Tags: discussion

As there have been several questions in languages other than English in recent days I think it is worth sharing this [Stack Exchange Policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

More specifically [the policy states](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/):

- Direct programmers to native language resources. Users who post non-English questions should be gently directed to programming forums in their own language. Community should form around the gravity of native human languages. (see: Chinatown, Little Italy, etc.) Feel free to post links to appropriate human language-specific resources.
- It is not our goal to teach English. It is our goal to teach programming. If the post has salvageable English and makes some modicum of sense, it should be edited and improved just like any other post. If it does not, it should be closed.
- The asker has to put effort into the question. Barging into an obviously English dominated forum and insisting on posting a question in another language is no different than the “do my work for me” sort of programming questions — the worst possible sin on Stack Overflow in my humble opinion. You want us to give you answers? Then prove that you’ve put some effort into the question, and you can begin by politely asking it in the language this community is formed around.

Having stated the above, I think we all want to help as many people as possible. Does anyone have an objection to community members that understand the language being used, helping to translate questions into English so that they comply with the above policy?

Assuming a sucessful translation into English valuable questions can be retained for the benefit of others in addition to the person who originally asked the question. Of course if no translations are offered in a timely manner the question would still need to be closed.